# SharePoint page recommendations

Tags: sharepoint-online

The SharePoint page recommendations webpart is shown only when the page is edited and republished.
Is there a way where we can enable this webpart by default when new post is created for first time.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations are not shown on newly created news posts. However, they will be displayed on edited posts once published.

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-page-recommendations-12bf4c4e-3452-4575-afd4-ef7536b027fa

Per my knowledge there is no way to make it displayed on newly created posts.